# Animate.css using for dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, animation, twitter-bootstrap-3, animate.css

**Hi guys..**

Just the question... I tried to make with animate.css and js animated dropdown menu
its working, 
but not  what i really want :)

I tried with **addClass** and **removeClass** but nothing....

Its possible to make animation -- hover on menu than open the dropdown.?

```
code:
    $(function() {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').hover(function() {
            $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').addClass('open animated fadeInDown');

        });
    });
```

If somebody have some idea please let me know :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the open class to your dropdown instead of your dropdown-menu:

```
$(function() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').hover(function() {
        $('.dropdown').addClass('open');
        $('.dropdown-menu').addClass('animated fadeInDown');

    });
    $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('animated fadeInDown');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are many dropdown menus, the above code will make all of them animate. I have done the following modifications to the answer's code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('open');
        $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').addClass('animated slideInDown');

    });
    $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
        $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('animated slideInDown');

    });
});
```